# Php-zmq segmentation fault

Tags: php, linux, apache, zeromq

I'm running apache in linux with PHP and a ZMQ binding.
When running this code for every page load it works fine:

```
$_SESSION['ZMQcontext'] = new ZMQContext(1);
$_SESSION['req'] = new ZMQSocket($_SESSION['ZMQcontext'], ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);
$_SESSION['req']->connect("tcp://localhost:30000");

// Set maximum wait time on receive to 250 milliseconds
$_SESSION['req']->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_RCVTIMEO, 250);
```

But then I thought I shouldn't create a new ZMQ context and connect the socket for each page load so then I wrote it like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['ZMQcontext'])) {
  $_SESSION['ZMQcontext'] = new ZMQContext(1);
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['req'])) {
  $_SESSION['req'] = new ZMQSocket($_SESSION['ZMQcontext'], ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);
  $_SESSION['req']->connect("tcp://localhost:30000");

  // Set maximum wait time on receive to 250 milliseconds
  $_SESSION['req']->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_RCVTIMEO, 250);
}
```

Now I got this in the Apache error log:

```
[notice] child pid 10411 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

So does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Is the ZMQ context stored in a PHP local memory address? I thought that it should be stored in a memory address that Apche should be able to find when using the $_SESSION variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should setSockOpt() before connect(), but I don't know if the Segmentation fault related to this.

> Caution: All options, with the exception of ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE and ZMQ_LINGER, only take effect for subsequent socket bind/connects.

http://api.zeromq.org/2-2:zmq-setsockopt